# Visual Studio 2019 lock toolbar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

This is my toolbar:

[image]
How can I lock the Visual Studio toolbar so that the element groups are not movable? From time to time the order changes. This is a bit annoying :D

I can't find the settings for this. I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it is not possible to lock the actual element groups or toolbars themselves as discussed in another post here: [Lock down placement of panes from visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463739/lock-down-placement-of-panes-from-visual-studio)

As described you can reset the 'stock' layout however with the following command:

```
Window -> Reset Windows Layout
```

Hope this answers your question.

Best regards